# How to open Default email client with attachment in angular5 with .Net core?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am using Angularcli (angular 5)  with .net core, in my application  need to open default mail client with attachment. You guys have any idea how to make this possible?

Comment: Try using "mailTo: email@nothing.com" in href of anchor tab ( <a> ), I don't remember if you can pass the attachment, although I think it depends in the mail client if it accepts or not the attachment. Search google for mailTo:

Comment: I tried this way but mailto doesn't support attachment because of security reason.

Comment: There is no way to pass an attachment using `mailto`, only subject and body can be added this way. My best bet at a workaround for this would be to build a web form to attach and send the file instead of relying on the user's email client.